# Проблема с подсветкой socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, typescript

```
 this.socketio = new io.connect(RealtimeMultiplayerGame.Constants.SERVER_SETTING.GET_URI(), {
      transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
      reconnect: false,
      rememberTransport: false
 });
```

Пишет:

> Error:(79, 29) TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the
>   'new' keyword.
>
> Error:(81, 29) TS7009: 'new' expression, whose target lacks a
>   construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

В интерфейсе:

```
/**
 * @see the default constructor (io(uri, opts))
 */
 connect( uri: string, opts?: SocketIOClient.ConnectOpts ): SocketIOClient.Socket;

 /**
 * @see the default constructor (io(opts))
 */
 connect( opts?: SocketIOClient.ConnectOpts ): SocketIOClient.Socket;
```

Не понимаю как пофиксить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод `connect` не требует `new`

```
this.socketio = io.connect(RealtimeMultiplayerGame.Constants.SERVER_SETTING.GET_URI(), {
    transports: ['websocket', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
    reconnect: false,
    rememberTransport: false
});
```